# How to pass objects to and fro between activities in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

With some basic knowledge in this area, to pass data between multiple `Activities` i have created `Parcelable` class.

My two `Activities` structure looks similar to the below image,

[image]

where within the `onClick` event listener of `button1`, i have the below code snippet to pass the `selectedText` (where the value of selectedText is "Header text" which in displayed above the button1)

```
 ParcelableClass _ParcelableClass = new ParcelableClass(selectedText);
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Editor.class);
 intent.putExtra("_ParcelableClass",ParcelableClass);
 startActivity(intent);
```

In the `ParcelableClass` i can `read` and `write` the values, so that `selectedText` can be assigned to the `EditText` available in the second activity.

**where my requirement is to pass the edited text (`new Header text`) to the first activity when `Ok` button is selected, based on that `selectedText` in the first activity should also changed into "new Header Text".**

Do i need to created new Intent while click the `ok` button, if so it will create a new bundle for the first activity. so i just need to change the header value alone, based on the edited text in the second activity.

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android

Comment: it works :) seems like the question is duplicate, so i will close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use startActivityForResult(...) instead of startActivity(...)

Here's a simple example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Then from your second activity just set the data you want to return as an extra to the intent and set the result like this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

And finally, in your first activity you need to override onActivityResult(...).
Something like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically a direct copy of the accepted answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android. Either add something new, or flag as a duplicate.  At the very least, give attribution to the answer where you copied the code from.